# Ubuntu - 17.10 eth0 not available instead docker0 interface

Tags: ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 but i do not see etho and no IP starting with 192* rather i see docker0. I uninstalled docker but still no etho0. Please advise.

**Below is ifconfig command output:**

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:42:1a:d7:ec:42  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::52fa:91c6:e92f:3634  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 20:47:47:b1:42:19  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3325  bytes 2856661 (2.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3154  bytes 354702 (354.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7200000-f7220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 428  bytes 36916 (36.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 428  bytes 36916 (36.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```